# Given m vectors in n dimension where m>>>n, how do you find the vectors that define the largest convex hull constructed with the vectors?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, convex-hulls

Say there are m vectors in n dimensional space (m>>>n).
There exists a largest convex hull defined by a subset of those vectors.

My goal is to describe the space that is strictly inside the largest convex hull defined by these vectors, and outside the 2nd largest convex hull defined by these vectors where the 2nd largest convex hull is strictly inside the largest convex hull.

To do this, I would need to identify the vectors defining the largest convex hull, say $R_1$, and then extract those vectors from the set of m vectors, and construct another largest convex hull from the remaining vectors, say $R_2$. Then I can describe the objective space as $R_1-R_2$.

However, I cannot think of a suitable way to find the vectors that define the largest convex hull. Is there any thm / lemma / problem related to this?

Thanks

Comment: The largest convex hull is the convex hull of all the vectors.  It is the convex hull of its extreme points, so if you want a convex hull strictly inside this one you could remove those extreme points.

Comment: Yeah I know but is there a way to identify those extreme points? It's easy to do so on pictures but I was looking for some sort of mathematical description.

Comment: $p_i$ is an extreme point of the convex hull of $p_1, \ldots, p_m$ iff there exists $v$ with $v \cdot p_i \ge 1 + v\cdot p_j$ for all $j \ne i$.  You can use linear programming to decide this.

Comment: Thank you! Is there anything special about $v$ or is it just any scalar?

Comment: No, $v$ is a vector.

Comment: By the way, do you know of a reference that I could look at, for the definition of extreme point that you gave me?